# Branched coverings of the Riemann sphere

Tags: covering-spaces, riemann-sphere

Can someone give me an example of a non-trivial branched covering of the Riemann sphere?

Is there some way to enumerate all such coverings?

Is there any easy answer to the same questions about the torus?

Comment: lots of stuff on Google with your title

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the simpler example is the map $z \to z^2$ from $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ and then extended in the obvious way to a map from the Riemann sphere onto itself. Could you see where it has the ramification points ?

Comment: Thank you, you opened my eyes; it has the ramification points in $0$ and $\infty$. Actually any meromorphic function is a branched cover of the Riemann sphere.
What about the torus? What is a branched covering of it?

Comment: Yes indeed!, cheers.

Comment: But what about the torus?

Comment: Are you aware that you are going around of the so called Hurwitz Theorem ?. Namely, maps between compact Riemann surfaces or equivalently algebraic curves. Depending on your formation : algebraic or analytic I can suggest you some good books

Comment: I'm more of an analyst. I'd love some good book, but could you please give me also an example of a non-trivial branched covering of the torus? Thank you

Comment: Branched coverings comes usually as projections of a curve to anothe curve (see Figure 13 at page 299 in Hartshorne's "Algebraic Geometry" ). So to see a concrete example you take the product $T \times T$ of a torus and look for a curve $C \subset T \times T$ of genus $g > 1$. Then the projection to any one of the factors gives you two examples of branching covering of a torus.